# How to deploy a frontend and backend application on the same AzureDevops instance

Tags: reactjs, .net, azure, azure-devops

I need to deploy a frontend and backend application on the same WebApp using AzureDevops and configure the Pipeline using Azure Repos.

I thought of doing this by uploading the application front and back in the same repository in different folders. Then I would set up a Pipeline for each one using the Pipeline's Deployment Groups.

Would this solution be viable? Can you help me to find a solution?